# I am curious about Sticky among the position property of css

Tags: css

I studied css position.

I studied sticky, but if you don't declare the top property, the sticky doesn't apply, why?
Is top property declaration mandatory for sticky in position??
I'm curious about the principle and reason why it shouldn't be applied if I don't declare the top property.

It's a simple question. Please tell me

Answer (score 1):

As per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky)

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then **offset** relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.

Thus, value is required (e.g. top x or bottom x,  right, left etc) so the element knows *where* to stick.